# Specific Power (gravitometric power density) of gasoline?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, power, heat-engine

This may be off the mark, however I am having a difficulty in finding this piece of information as every search on Google provides results for the (gravitometric) energy density, the mJ/kg, or Wh/kg values.

However, I am interested to compare gasoline to the typical electric battery gravitometric power density (which is about 220 W/Kg), so I need the specific power (in kW/kg), not the energy capacity of the fuel.

Also, is there a way to convert these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power is how fast you can gather the energy from the store.

For a battery, you have heating limits that could cause damage above certain power levels, and you have chemical reaction limits at the electrodes that cap the power available.  These limits can be changed by the engineering of the battery, so they make sense to quote.

For gasoline, the limits are not on the fuel, but on the engine.  The rate the fuel can be added to the engine and still extract useful energy depends on fuel pumps, fuel lines, combustion chamber size, etc.  You modify the engine, not the fuel, to increase power limits.  There's no useful power value for gasoline independent of an engine.